# jQuery event binding issues with radio buttons

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to get jQuery to bind an onClick function when the document loads to my radio buttons.

ASP goes back to the database and finds all the open markers and then it sends a response to the page with the raw HTML to make a radio button and an image of the marker. What I need to do is have jQuery (or anything for that matter) bind an onClick that will signal what one is clicked so I can send that markerId back to the database to attach it to a person.

Here is a rough [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sDAWQ/1/) of what I've tried so far. In debugging I added alerts in the each function and I see them 3x like I should but the `attr('id')` comes back undefined.

This is the html that puts the radio buttons on the form

```
            <br />
            <p>Select open marker for new user:
            <% getMarkers(); %>
            </p>
```

This is the codebehind for that call

```
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (readIndex % 3 == 0)
                markerTable += "<tr>";

            string markerId = reader["marker_id"].ToString();
            string fileName = reader["marker_filename"].ToString();

            markerTable += "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"openMarker\" value=\"" + markerId + "\" " +
                "id=\"oMrk" + markerId + "\"><label for=\"oMrk" + markerId + "\"><img src=\"/Markers/" +
                fileName + "\" /></label></input></td>";

            readIndex++;

            if (readIndex % 3 == 0)
                markerTable += "</tr>";

        }

        if (readIndex % 3 != 0)
            markerTable += "</tr>";

        markerTable += "</table>";
    }
    else
        markerTable = "<p>No empty markers. Please delete a user to continue.</p>";
    
    sCon.Close();
    return markerTable;
```

The fiddle I posted has the source pasted into it from this function.

I have two questions.

1. Why does this not work? It seems like it should, I am getting 3 elements from my jQuery selector statement, It's being called from `$(document).ready()` why are the attributes undefined?
2. Is there a better way to do this? I was planning on putting the value in a page variable and then sending it with an ASP button back to the server to a stored procedure to add that marker with some text from another field back to the database. I realize I could add the onClick event into the response html, but dang it I need to understand why what I'm doing isn't working.

I'm pretty new to web, so if I am way off the mark procedurally, I am open for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/sDAWQ/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:radio').each(function (radElem) {
        var radId = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(radId);

    });

     $('input:radio').on('click', function () {
            alert('Clicked');
        });
});
```

Comment: That fixes my undefined problem but onClick is still not binding to onClick. (I've changed the radElem to this for the `on` function)

Comment: @Bmo  did you check the latest link i provided

Comment: It tells me I need to wait.

Comment: @Bmo  i think after some time only you can accept answer(I think 10 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:radio').on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Do you need to send the value to the server while staying on the page? (via ajax)

or do you need to post the form to another page?

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn't work because you are trying to bind `onClick` instead of
   just `click`
2. The other answers have provided the jQuery for you. In the each you
   just need to use `this` keyword

I tested this in a fiddle, it works. Others have provided similar answers, but here's the fiddle anyway: [THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kvYLf/1/)

> ```
> $(document).ready(function () {
>     $("input:radio").each(function () {
>         var radId = $(this).attr('id');
>         alert(radId);
>         $(this).on('click', function () {
>             alert('Clicked');
>         });
>     });
> });
> ```

As for a better way to do what you are trying to accomplish, I do not have a firm grasp of what you are trying to do really, sorry. It feels though, like you should be initially populating this in asp.net, but the constraints of your page may not make this possible. I can't say.

Also, go ahead and pick one of the previous answers, I just wanted to explain to you why what you had wasn't working.